# Username and Password in URL

Tags: javascript, xml, http

I am trying to load an XML file that asks for a username and password.

The code I'm using is as follows that I am trying to send the username and password in the URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://admin:admin@192.168.0.5/myfile.xml",false);
```

The full code of my page looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="test1" name="test1" cols="90" rows="30">
XML file will be displayed here
</textarea><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("test1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
     } else
     {
     alert('Panel not communicating.Reason: '+xmlhttp.status);
     }
   }

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://admin:admin@192.168.0.5/myfile.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what error are you getting? are you sure that the remote server accepts HTTP Basic Auth?

Comment: So what happens when you type the URL into a browser window?

Comment: I don't get any error messages it just sits there, but if I remove the username and password from the URL code it will ask for a username and password which I can manually enter in and it works fine, but I want to do it automatically. any ideas?

Comment: i think you need to pass them in a header instead of the url

Comment: what do you mean by that?? I am not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it working by doing the following:

Change:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://admin:admin@192.168.0.5/myfile.xml",false);
```

To:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://admin:admin@192.168.0.5/myfile.xml",false,"username","password");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add this function to create the authorization header contents:

```
function make_base_auth(user, password)
{
  var tok = user + ':' + pass;
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
```

Then, call the function and store the return value in a separate variable:

```
var auth = make_basic_auth('admin', 'admin');
```

Lastly, pass the value of `auth` to the `XMLHttpRequest` object:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
xmlhttp.send();
```

---

Attribution: http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

See this question for a similar scenario. [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax) Note one answer states that IE does not support credentials in a URL (as you are attempting to do).